# Удаление строки таблицы по клику кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно сделать, чтобы можно было выбрать строку и удалить её по одной кнопке. Вот так получается, если кнопка будет для каждой строки:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
  });
</script>

<table id="myTable" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
 <td><input type='button' value='Удалить' style='font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer;' class='btnDelete'/></td>
</tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
 <td><input type='button' value='Удалить' style='font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer;' class='btnDelete'/></td>
</tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
 <td><input type='button' value='Удалить' style='font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer;' class='btnDelete'/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Но нужно именно, чтобы была одна кнопка, выделяешь одну строку, жмёшь эту кнопку и строка удаляется.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    $('.table tr').click(function(){
        $('.table tr').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    $fordel=$(this).children('td:first-child').text();
  alert($fordel);
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
  });
</script>
<style>
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
}
.table td {
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hover */
.table .hover td:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 105%;
    border-top: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
}
.table .hover td:first-child:after {
    border-left: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
}
.table .hover td:last-child:after {
    border-right: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
    width: auto;
}

/* Click */
.table .active td:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 105%;
    border-top: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
}
.table .active td:first-child:after {
    border-left: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
}
.table .active td:last-child:after {
    border-right: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
<table id="myTable" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type='button' value='Удалить' style='font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer;' class='btnDelete'/>
```

У каждой строки будет свой id, вроде я получаю его в $fordel (сохраняется ли это значение вообще где-то?). Ну и вот с помощью одной кнопки по этому id надо как-то удалять строки.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант, можно при клике пользователя на любой td или tr добавлять к tr класс 'del' - .addClass('del') а потом при клике на кнопку удалить, пройти циклом и удалить все ненужные строки:

```
$("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
   $('.del').each(function( index ) {
      $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

P.S.
Добавить класс "del" для тыка на td

```
$('tr td').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('del');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас ошибки в разметке
2. Вы содрали код, и даже не разбирались как он работает.
3. При клике по строке таблицы вам надо сохранить ссылку на элемент.
4. А уже когда кликаете по кнопке удалить строку. В нашем случае, мы сохранили  объект `jquery` в котором хранится ссылка на элемент. Дальше вызываем метод удаления.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });

  $('.table tr').click(function() {
    $('.table tr').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    element_tr = $(this);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnDelete").on('click', function() {
    element_tr.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<style>
  .table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
  }
  
  .table td {
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* Hover */
  
  .table .hover td:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 105%;
    border-top: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
  }
  
  .table .hover td:first-child:after {
    border-left: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
  }
  
  .table .hover td:last-child:after {
    border-right: 3px solid #AFDAFC;
    width: auto;
  }
  /* Click */
  
  .table .active td:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 105%;
    border-top: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
  }
  
  .table .active td:first-child:after {
    border-left: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
  }
  
  .table .active td:last-child:after {
    border-right: 3px solid #0AA9FF;
    width: auto;
  }
</style>
<table id="myTable" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type='button' value='Удалить' style='font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer;' id='btnDelete' />
```